# Vba, get Cells value but point is replace by commat

Tags: excel, vba, replace, point

I set a value of Cell like this :

```
MsgBox (i) 'print 1.1
Cells(2,3) = i
```

The Cell (in Excel) doesn't display 1.1 but 1,1 ! 
Why the point is replaced by a commat (Im French and I check the Excel options but I don't find the solution..)

Thanks =)

Comment: By default the numeric separator in your language notation is comma`,` so you need to insert your value as a string instead of number.

Comment: Why display with the dot.  The French decimal separator is comma; the VBA decimal separator is the dot.  Excel will use the decimal separator as shown in Control Panel/Windows REgional settings

Answer (score 0):

Right clic and format => Text =)
And your solution is good Slyx I think !

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the problem is that your system decimal separator is the comma.  If you want to change it in Excel, you can try something like

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim I As Double
    I = 1.1
    Cells(1, 1) = I
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = ","
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
End Sub
```